# Inconsistent Flag UI in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

When flagging in chat, there are currently 3 places to do so.

1. On the right side of a message, when hovering over it.
2. In the message menu, when hovering, then clicking on the arrow next to a message
3. At the bottom of the message menu, same place as #2.

[image: The first place to flag]

[image: The second and third place to flag]

Flag buttons 1 and 2 don't offer the same UI as 3, which offers the ability to add a reason to the flag.

[image]

I believe that a few changes should be made here.

1. Combine #2 and #3.
2. Add the message box to #1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion about adding more reason for spam/offensive is well-noted. Indeed, we've made much of the main Q&A flags require more detail there (even on comments) - maybe chat is an iteration behind.

<s>I'm not sure I agree on the star, though. If it isn't obvious from context why something is star-worthy, I'm not sure it is ;p We don't require reasons for question upvotes, for comparison.</s>

Comment: I'm not at all asking about the star. I'm pointing out the Flag as spam/offensive, beneath it, and beneath that, the flag for moderator. I think the two should be combined and that the "why" box should be in location 1 as well.

Comment: @Moshe - oh, right; then I agree